# PHP - split an array based on missing keys

Tags: php, arrays, split

So here's my code:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [23] => 23 [24] => 24 )
```

It's missing some keys and I'd like to split this array in two based on those missing keys and then display the highest and lowest keys from those two arrays...

EX: 0-8 & 23-24

Help!

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve **your** problem?

Comment: I've tried, but honestly theres no php functions i've seen to solve this

Comment: All you need is one for loop and a little bit think =) (There is no php side solution for this problem)

Comment: I'm sure php allows to use more than one function in a program. Can you describe the total algorithm by regular words, as a list of steps to perform to get the desired results?

Comment: I have an array of 24 hours. 0 to 24 where the keys match the values. I unset a few hours in the middle of the array therefore removing the keys and values. I now want to show the lowest and highest values/keys from each side of the gap(missing keys)

Comment: Aside from asking for help, __what__ have you tried.... otherwise this simply looks as though you're asking someone to do all the work for you... show us the logic you use to decide which hours to unset, and you might be able to build your min/max sets at that point

Comment: well, you input the hours that you work, say 17-22, and it unsets all those keys from the array. Then I need it to tell me the start and end times of your time off, 0-16 and 23-24 in this case

Comment: @cameron - SHOW CODE... will there only ever be two blocks 0-x and y-24, or could there be one block of x-y, or 3 or 4 blocks if people have split shifts?

Comment: `code
$hours = range(0, 24);
$alldays = array($hours, $hours, $hours, $hours, $hours, $hours, $hours);
$daynames = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

$daysdone=0;
while($daysdone < 7) {
 echo $daynames[$daysdone] . ': ';
 foreach($alldays[$daysdone] as $x) {
  echo $x . ' ';
 }
 echo '<br>';
 $daysdone++;
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code may be solve your problems:

```
$arr = array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "4" => "4", "5" => "5", "8" => "8", "9" => "9", "10" => "10", "11" => "11", "12" => "12", "16" => "16");
$arr_result = array();

$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);

$start = intval($arr_keys[0]);
$end = intval($arr_keys[count($arr_keys)-1]);

$group_idx = 0;

$idx = $start;
foreach($arr_keys as $x => $key) {
    if (intval($key) == intval($idx)) {
        $arr_result[$group_idx][$key] = $arr[$key];
        $idx++;
    } else {
        $group_idx++;
        $arr_result[$group_idx][$key] = $arr[$key];
        $idx = intval($key) + 1;
    }

}

print_r($arr_result);
```

i tested it, and run perfectly like your request :). And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 9
            [10] => 10
            [11] => 11
            [12] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [16] => 16
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array ("0" => 0, "1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => 4, "5" => 5, "6" => 6, "7" => 7, "8" => 8, "23" => 23, "24" => 24, "25" => 25, "27" => 27, "28" => 28);

$full = range(reset($test),end($test));
$diff = (array_diff($full,$test));
$found = FALSE;
$start = reset($test);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($full); $i++)
    {
    if (array_key_exists($i, $diff))
        {
        if (!$found)
            {
            $str[] = $start."-".($i-1);
            $start = NULL;
            }

        $found = TRUE;
        }
    else
        {
        if (is_null($start))
            $start = $i;
        $found = FALSE;
        }
    }

$str[] = $start."-".($i-1);

print_r($str);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-8
    [1] => 23-25
    [2] => 27-28
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours = range(0,24);
for($i = 5; $i <= 16; ++$i)
    unset ($hours[$i]);

foreach($hours as $key => $hour) {
    $hours[$key] = array($hour);
    if (isset($hours[$key-1])) {
        $hours[$key] = $hours[$key-1];
        $hours[$key][1] = $hour;
        unset($hours[$key-1]);
    }

}
$hours = array_values($hours);

var_dump($hours);
```